# Conditions for an Operator to Map Onto

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let operator $A[f(x)]=g(x)f(x)$ such that $A:C[a,b] \rightarrow C[a,b]$. I'm trying to think of the necessary and sufficient conditions needed on $g(x)$ such that the map is onto.

Obviously it needs to be continuous over the given interval, but I cannot think of any other conditions, and I feel like there are more. Maybe the need to also be invertible? Thanks for any help, I know it's a bit simple but it's giving me a bit of trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the map is onto, there is some function $f$ such that $gf=1$. So, $g$ needs to be invertible.

Now suppose $g$ is invertible. Let $f \in C[a,b]$. Then $A(g^{-1}f)=f$. So, $A$ is onto.